# android version with kernel debug symbols

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, android-source

I'm trying to generate a custom android image, to run under the emulator, using a kernel version compiled by myself (the idea is to include debug symbols). I found a lot of information on google about it so I checked out the branch android-goldfish-4.14-dev, and tried to compile it a couple of times, but this crash happens any time I run the compiled kernel.

```
[    0.851597]  ? generic_make_request+0x123/0x300
[    0.852314]  submit_bio+0x73/0x140
[    0.852854]  ? bio_alloc_bioset+0xcc/0x1e0
[    0.853504]  ? submit_bio+0x73/0x140
[    0.854052]  ? guard_bio_eod+0x2c/0xf0
[    0.854622]  submit_bh_wbc+0x180/0x1b0
[    0.855195]  __bread_gfp+0x54/0xe0
[    0.855744]  ext4_fill_super+0x1f6/0x3a10
[    0.856377]  ? vsnprintf+0x24f/0x4e0
[    0.856943]  ? down_write+0x12/0x40
[    0.857497]  ? snprintf+0x45/0x70
[    0.858021]  mount_bdev+0x17f/0x1b0
[    0.858572]  ? mount_bdev+0x17f/0x1b0
[    0.859149]  ? ext4_calculate_overhead+0x490/0x490
[    0.859896]  ext4_mount+0x15/0x20
[    0.860420]  mount_fs+0x155/0x180
[    0.860942]  ? alloc_vfsmnt+0x1bb/0x230
[    0.861547]  vfs_kern_mount.part.23+0x80/0x150
[    0.862240]  do_mount+0x5ea/0xd20
[    0.862764]  ? memdup_user+0x4f/0x80
[    0.863329]  SyS_mount+0x98/0xe0
[    0.863842]  mount_block_root+0x109/0x2da
[    0.864478]  ? set_debug_rodata+0x17/0x17
[    0.865107]  mount_root+0x6a/0x6d
[    0.865634]  prepare_namespace+0x13e/0x176
[    0.866287]  kernel_init_freeable+0x224/0x251
[    0.866971]  ? rest_init+0xb0/0xb0
[    0.867507]  kernel_init+0xe/0x101
[    0.868045]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
```

I'm trying to compile it for running under qemu x86.

Another possibility can be get an android oreo image with the kernel debug symbols; do you know if there are precompiled images with kernel debug symbols?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the emulator you want to run kernel on? Does it emulate some particular device? Do you know which defconfig you want to use for that? Also, which exactly kernel version you want to run?

Comment: Now, I'm trying to use the kernel 4.14.74 and run it under the qemu-x86 emulator. I don't want any special defconfig configuration. I just want to run an android instance with this kernel version and its symbols. After compiling that, I got a NULL ptr crash trying to load the ext4 filesystem.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your actual issue. Were you able to successfully run any other Android images under qemu? Can it be something related to qemu? Or maybe you have some kernel modules (on vendor or system partition) built for another kernel version and this is the reason for the crash? In other words: please provide instructions on how you built your kernel and how you run it on qemu, and also please share that crash dump. If you want to, I can describe how to build Android kernel 4.14 for real ARM devices, but not sure it'll help in your case.

Comment: Hi Sam! thx for your help. I modified the question to provide you a little more information about the issue. if you can give me a link with the instructions to compile the android kernel I will be ok!. thx again ;)

Comment: I've added build instructions in the answer. But I wonder which exactly QEMU do you use, and using which cmd line? As I remember, for Android you should use modified QEMU called "Android Emulator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is actually in kernel, below are instructions how to build it from sources.

### 1. Obtain kernel sources

First of all, you need to figure out the device which you want to build the kernel for. Knowing the device name, you can clone correct Android kernel sources for it and build it. For example, for goldfish you should use kernel from:

https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish/

If you're not sure which kernel to use for your device, try to use so called "Android common kernel":

https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/

Basically it works like this:

- Android common kernel is based on regular Linux kernel, adding some Android-specific  patches on top of it
- Android kernels for specific devices are based on common kernel, adding some device-specific patches on top of it.

Now that you "git cloned" the kernel, checkout to version branch you want to use:

```
$ git checkout android-4.14
```

### 2. Configure toolchain

I assume you want to build kernel for x86_64 architecture. If so, configure  your toolchain like this:

```
$ export PATH=$AOSP_DIR/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/x86_64-linux-android-4.9/bin:$PATH
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-linux-androidkernel-
$ export ARCH=x86_64
```

where `$AOSP_DIR` -- path to your AOSP sources. If you don't have AOSP sources, you can obtain the toolchain separately (outside of kernel sources directory):

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/x86_64-linux-android-4.9
```

### 3. Obtain Android kernel configs

Download Android kernel configs (outside of your kernel directory):

```sh
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/configs android-kernel-configs
```

### 4. Configure and build the kernel

Now, in your kernel source code directory, you can create kernel configuration (`.config` file) using corresponding defconfig file and Android config fragments. For example, for goldfish you should use this command:

```
$ ./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh \
    arch/x86/configs/x86_64_ranchu_defconfig \
    ../android-kernel-configs/android-4.14/android-base.config \
    ../android-kernel-configs/android-4.14/android-recommended.config \
    ../android-kernel-configs/android-4.14/android-recommended-x86.config
```

Now `.config` file is generated. At this point you may want to run `make menuconfig` and modify the kernel configuration for your needs (e.g. enable some debug options, etc).

Build the kernel:

```
$ make -j4
```

---

It should built fine, but I didn't test it (neither the building, nor the running in the emulator). So if you can verify if those instructions work, please provide your comments.

Comment: yes! I just added a previous .config file extracted from a running android instance. (adb pull /proc/config.gz).  In my case; I activate the following kernel configuration flags: CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS, CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO, CONFIG_MEMCG, CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP, CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP_ENABLE (I had to activate the MEMCG flags because on the other way, the kernel doesn't boot)

Comment: @user4547829 Good to hear that it works for you now! `CONFIG_MEMCG` options should be added from `android-base.config`, when you merge it into defconfig, as shown in my answer. Would be cool if you can share your command (with parameters) for running emulator with kernel image and Android images, and where you get that emulator from.